# MarkLogic User Management with Last-Login database

Tags: rest, xquery, marklogic, user-management, marklogic-8

I'm trying to manage LDAP authenticated users on MarkLogic. I want to be able to check the Last-login value for each user. I would like to do this from the REST interface. However, MarkLogic will only return a document that shows my administrative user's login activity. This is also true from the qconsole. If I **Explore** the **Last-Login** content source, all login documents are shown and I can view the contents. I'd like to be able to get the document with xquery and REST.

```
xdmp:user-last-login(xdmp:user("myCurrentUser"))
```

returns:

```
<last-login xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/last-login">
  <user-id>191939440856729280</user-id>
  <last-successful-login>2017-03-14T18:16:13Z</last-successful-login>
  <last-unsuccessful-login>
  </last-unsuccessful-login>
  <number-unsuccessful-logins>0</number-unsuccessful-logins>
  <display-last-login>true</display-last-login>
</last-login>
```

If I try to look at another user with myCurrentUser (Who is admin), I get:

```
xdmp:user-last-login(xdmp:user("someOtherUser"))
```

returns:

*your query returned an empty sequence*

I'd like to be able to get someOtherUser's last login value. I want to monitor who is not using my cluster and then remove them if they are not actively using the cluster. Is this the best way to do this? Is there a better way? Is this even possible with MarkLogic?

```
for i in (list of LDAP names)
do
    curl -s --anyauth --user myUser:$(cat pass) -X POST -i \
    -d "xquery=xquery version \"1.0-ml\";xdmp:user-last-login(xdmp:user(\""$i"\"))" \
    -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    "http://$(hostname):8000/v1/eval"
done
```

Comment: After re-reading the MarkLogic documentation, it looks like **another** bug. https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:user-last-login

Comment: What version of MarkLogic are you running?

Comment: I'm trying this on 8.0-5.4 and 8.0-6. Both of these are on CentOS 6.8 fully patched. I've turned stemmed search to `basic` on the Last-Login database. App-Services appserver has the last login option assigned to the `Last-Login` db.

Comment: I'm also attempting to do this with `cts:search(fn:doc(),xs:string(xdmp:user('differentUser')))`. This works on the qconsole. However, I only get a 200 response from curl but no data. `curl --anyauth --user admin:$(cat pass) -X POST -i -d "xquery=xquery version \"1.0-ml\";cts:search(fn:doc(),xs:string(xdmp:user('${OTHER-USER}')))" -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY" "http://localhost:8000/v1/eval"`

Comment: Adding a database parameter to my http: statement got me the results I wanted. I added this `?database=Last-Login` 
To This:
`-X POST -i -d "xquery=xquery version \"1.0-ml\";cts:search(fn:doc(),xs:string(xdmp:user('${OTHER-‌​USER}')))" -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY" "http://localhost:8000/v1/eval?database=Last-Login"`

Comment: (My last post was missing some info.) Adding a database parameter to my http: statement got me the results I wanted. I added this `?database=Last-Login` 
To This:
`curl --anyauth --user admin:$(cat pass) -X POST -i -d "xquery=xquery version \"1.0-ml\";cts:search(fn:doc(),xs:string(xdmp:user('${OTHER-‌​USER}')))" -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY" "http://localhost:8000/v1/eval?database=Last-Login"`

Answer (score 2):

It turns out we have a bug listed in our system indicating that `xdmp:user-last-login()` takes a user id parameter, but returns information for the current user.

As a workaround, I suggest writing a [REST extension](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#chapter) that answer what you're looking for. Something like this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

module namespace last = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/last-login";

declare namespace ll = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/last-login";

declare option xdmp:mapping "false";

declare function last:get(
    $context as map:map,
    $params  as map:map
) as document-node()*
{
  let $user-id :=
    try {
      xdmp:user(map:get($params, "username"))
    } catch ($e) {
      if ($e/error:code = "SEC-USERDNE") then ()
      else xdmp:rethrow()
    }
  return
    if ($user-id) then (
      document {
        xdmp:invoke-function(
          function() {
            /ll:last-login[ll:user-id = $user-id]
          },
          map:entry("database", xdmp:database("Last-Login"))
        )
      }
    )
    else (
      map:put($context, "output-status", (400, "No such user"))
    )
};
```

This checks in the Last-Login database. It's hard-coded to that right now; calling `admin:appserver-get-last-login` would be better.

To deploy:

```
$ curl --anyauth --user user:password -X PUT \
  -H "Content-type: application/xquery" -d@"./last.xqy" \
  "http://localhost:8000/LATEST/config/resources/last-login?method=get&get:username=xs:string"
```

And call:

```
$ curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X GET \
  "http://localhost:8000/LATEST/resources/last-login?rs:username=admin"
```

Note the "rs:" in front of the username parameter, which is required by the REST API.